# One onclick button to handle multiple click event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have three functions that I want to execute with a button click.
    The three functions will be executed in this order:

1. ValuesChange()
2. SwitchTab()
3. Save()

But it seems because both the `SwitchTab()` and `Save()` uses click event handler, the button does not execute both functions.

All three functions are correct as I could execute them independently.
Would somebody please let me know what could be done to make the button work?

Thanks

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function Save() {
          $('master_btnApply').click();
        }

        function SwitchTab() {
          $('.tab_1812').click();
        }

        function ValuesChange(fieldID, assignedValue) {
             var valueArray = new Array(1);
             valueArray[0] = assignedValue;
             ArcherTech.UI.GenericContent.GetInstance().setFieldValue(fieldID, valueArray, '');
             SwitchTab();
             Save();
        }

 </script>

 <input type = "button" value = "Click" onclick="ValuesChange('18345', '67757');">
```

Comment: I don't think that code does what you think it does, and I think that's your problem.

Comment: there is mostly an error in your $('master_btnApply') selector, maybe $('#master_btnApply') for a id attribute. master_btnApply will select a tag <master_btnApply>.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this would work or not but can you just do

```
onclick="ValuesChange('18345', '67757');SwitchTab();Save();"
```

and take the SwitchTab and Save calls out of your ValuesChange function?